# Unable to get response from Jest test for an async-await-try-catch function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, async-await, jestjs

I am writing a simple jest test for async-await function which uses try-catch style syntax;

Unfortunately the function doesn't return the response; I known I am missing something very silly. I could use an extra pair of eyes.

PS: most of Internet resources focus on plain async-await but not many focus on async-await-try-catch; Hence asking on SO.

```
async justAnotherAsyncAwait () {
    try {
        console.log(`inside async await`);
        return Promise.resolve('HIIII');
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

expect(justAnotherAsyncAwait()).resolves.toEqual('HIIII')
```

the console reads  `inside async-await`

Comment: I think you are missing await before returning the Promise result. You can return after awaiting for the Promise to resolve.

Comment: This post might help https://blog.grossman.io/how-to-write-async-await-without-try-catch-blocks-in-javascript/

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala that doesn't seem to work;
Besides await-to-js, is there a native way of handling this ???

Answer (score 1):

[`resolves`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#resolves) and [`rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#rejects) both require you to either return the `Promise`:

```
test('justAnotherAsyncAwait', () => {
  // return the Promise
  return expect(justAnotherAsyncAwait()).resolves.toBe('HIIII');  // Success!
});
```

...or use an `async` test function and call `await` on the `Promise`:

```
test('justAnotherAsyncAwait', async () => {  // <= async test function
  // await the Promise
  await expect(justAnotherAsyncAwait()).resolves.toBe('HIIII');  // Success!
});
```

---

One other note:

An `async` function *always* returns a `Promise` and the `Promise` it returns will resolve to the returned value or reject with an `Error` if an `Error` is thrown, so you typically don't need to use a `try / catch` in the `async` function body.

Here is a simple example:

```
const func = async (arg) => {
  if (arg === 'pass') {
    return 'HIIII';
  }
  throw new Error('something bad happened');
}

test('justAnotherAsyncAwait', async () => {
  await expect(func('pass')).resolves.toBe('HIIII');  // Success!
  await expect(func()).rejects.toThrow('something bad happened');  // Success!
});
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with this method when the function itself is a class member and thus there's no reference to it as a variable so I'm wrapping it in an anonymous function but the server keeps exiting before the `await expect` call completes.

Answer (score 0):

```
const justAnotherAsyncAwait = async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`inside async await`);
        return  await Promise.resolve('HIIII');
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

describe('simple async await test', () => {
  it('resolve HIIII', () => {
    expect(justAnotherAsyncAwait()).resolves.toEqual('HIIII')
  });
});
```